# Logical query processing phase of INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE in SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am curious about the logical query processing phase of SQL queries.

For `SELECT` queries, the logical query processing phase order is:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

What is the order for `INSERT`, for `UPDATE` and for `DELETE`?

Comment: it is still the same as SELECT. The affected rows are determine first before any action is performed

Comment: So it's about sql-server or mysql?

Comment: it's about sql-server

Comment: Depends what you mean by ' logical query processing phase'. If you take a look at the query plan you can see SORTS (ORDER BY) earlier than joins in the actual plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to know what the actual query processing order is, take a look at the execution plan. That will tell you step by step exactly what SQL Server is doing.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank u.. Mr.Jonathan Allen

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server: [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)**

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

Comment: Hi michael.. thank u for the answer. Can you explain what about insert  ,update and delete query ..

Comment: @Sruthy My understanding is there is no difference. A query plan of a Select/Update/Insert/Delete has no difference apart from the final operator. I'm struggling to find sources to back up my belief though. I welcome anyone who has evidence to the contrary however.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and could not find an answer on the internet.
So i tried to logically derive the answer.
Here is a simple UPDATE statement (with alias a for the table):

```
UPDATE tbl_employees a
  SET a.Name = 'Anna'
  WHERE a.Id = 122;
```

Obviously, whether SET nor WHERE can be performed before the table is identified, so UPDATE must be the first logical step. Proof: Alias a is working (in Microsoft Access).

Before applying the SET Statement, one needs to know what records to apply it on. So WHERE must go as the second logical step (omitting WHERE would alter all records in the table)

Applying the SET Statement on the WHERE-filtered recordset must be the third step.

Summing up, the logical processing order must be:

1. UPDATE (~equivalent to FROM)
2. WHERE
3. SET (~equivalent to SELECT)

Any other order seems absurd (can you hypothetically think of any other order?).

Once again, its my own logical derivation. I dont know for sure. I would appriciate any link to a serious internet resource.